# Define Javascript functions to be always accessible by your browser's console

Tags: javascript, global-variables

How does one define global, and always accessible javascript functions in a particular browser's dev tools console?

Similar to defining a method in your ~/.irbrc for having a Ruby method on hand at all times.

**edit:**
I want to define these functions so that, if I exit my web browser, they'll still be defined when I re-open my browser!

Comment: `window.functionName = function(){ ...code... }` should generally do it.

Comment: Oh (after edit), you'd need a userscript, browser extension or to look into Chrome DevTools snippets

Comment: If you are using chrome, you can use Tampermonkey (search on app store)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bookmarklet. This is a short piece of javascript that executes as a bookmark.

Right-click on the bookmarks bar and press "add new page".

When it asks for the url, type something like:

```
javascript:window.myFunction = function() { /* code */ }
```

It will then be accessible via the javascript console whenever you click on the bookmark.

Alternatively, if you would like to immediately execute the function rather than simply making it available to the console, use:

```
javascript:(function() { /* code */ })()
```

If you want the script to run automatically without having to click on the bookmarklet everytime you navigate to a new page, you can install Tampermonkey, Greasemonkey or similar extensions.